# Unable to find the distance using HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, arduino-ultra-sonic

I am trying to find the distance to a nearby object using an HC SR04 ultrasonic sensor. I followed the tutorial from the below link:

[HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Range Sensor on the Raspberry Pi](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-range-sensor-on-the-raspberry-pi)

I replicated all the instructions as given. I ran into a problem when trying to run the code.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Setting the GPIO pins mode
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Setting the pin values
TRIG = 23
ECHO = 24

# Assigning the pins to GPIO
GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)

# Allowing the sensor to settle down
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
print('Waiting for thr sensor to settle down!!')
time.sleep(2)

# Sending a trigger pulse of 10 micro seconds duration
GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

# Starting the measurement process
pulse_start = 0
pulse_end = 0

# Checking for the last timestamp at which the ECHO is OFF
while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
    print('Running ECHO = 0 loop')
    pulse_start = time.time()

print('Pulse start: ',pulse_start)

# Checking for the last timestamp at which the ECHO is ON
while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
    print('Running ECHO = 1 loop')
    pulse_end = time.time()

print('Pulse end: ',pulse_end)

# Calculating the pulse duration
pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

# Distance Calc
distance = round((343/2)*pulse_duration,2)
print('Distance: ', distance, 'm')

# Cleaning up the pins
GPIO.cleanup()
```

The code doesn't seem to enter the first while loop where the ECHO pin is being checked for low signal. This is giving me a problem in calculating the distance. The output from the above code is as follows:

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6X0W.png)

Can anyone point out what the problem could be?

Comment: It seems like your ECHO pin is always ON, is your setup properly wired?

Comment: I'd try deleting these `print('Running ECHO = X loop')` statements and moving those `print('Pulse X: ',pulse_X)` statements to just before the `pulse_duration` calculation like this: https://codeshare.io/G8DB3J

Comment: @GabrielMilan How can the ECHO pin always be ON? Sorry for this question as I am from a mechE background

Comment: Have you tried changing those `print` statements, as I said above? And your ECHO pin would always be ON if you've wired it wrong, by connecting the voltage divider on +3V3 instead of GND

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, I have tried changing those print statements but the output still remains the same, The value assigned to pulse_start is still 0. I will once again try to rewire the setup.

Comment: One thing I would also check is whether the pins are connected correctly on the GPIO. You've set `TRIG = 23` and `ECHO = 24` on the code, please be sure that they correspond to your wiring setup. Besides that, I've made a few changes on your code in an attempt of making it work: https://codeshare.io/amrvl1 . Please let me know if I can help with anything else

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I rewired the setup once again and also took care of the points you mentioned above. I also changed the code by following your link. But it's causing the same issue.

Comment: @Akhil2511 The distance value as shown in your screenshot is too high. Is it possible the sensor cannot detect distances bigger than a specific value?